# Executing a php script from C

Tags: php, c++, c

I am trying to write a c program that executes a PHP script.
I tried using php_execute_script function that I came across in my google search.
However, it seems I have to call TSRMLS_FETCH() which throws an exception.
Does anyone have an idea why? or how should I do this in the proper way?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a bit more context?

Answer (score 4):

you can use `exec` function:

```
exec ("php myscript.php");
```

or you can use `popen`:

```
FILE *p;
p = popen("php myscript.php","r");
pclose(p);
```

Comment: I want a solution that does not open another process. Does any one know how to use php_execute_script correctly ?

Comment: could you provide link to php_execute_script that you use

Answer (score 0):

What you want is embedding the PHP interpreter.
You may try [PHPEmbed](https://github.com/facebook/phpembed) from the facebook github

Comment: I tried using it, but I get an access violation when I call the php_* functions. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post your code (or at least the part that's causing the acces violation)?

Comment: And btw are you using a php built with  --enable-embed passed to the configure script?